# XSD Error Regarding Order of <xs:choice /> and <xs:attribute /> Elements

Tags: xml, xsd

## TL;DR

Does XSD require that attributes must follow the `<xsd:choice />` element
(and presumably `<xs:sequence />` as well)?  If so, where can I find this
information, as I've been unable to locate it?

## Full Version

I'm writing my first XSD to validate an XML file.  When I validate my XML
against my XSD using the [XML Validator at FreeFormatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html), I get the
following error:

> S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of '#AnonType_Container' Is Invalid.
>   Element 'choice' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.

However, if I make change the XSD so that this line in the `Container`
specification

```
<xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:ID" use="required" />
```

follows the `<xs:choice />` element instead of preceding it, it works as
expected.

My questions are:

- Is it a requirement of the XSD Schema that attributes must follow the
  `<xsd:choice />` element (and presumably `<xsd:sequence />` as well,
  although I haven't confirmed that this fails), or is this a quirk of the
  validator I'm using?
- If this is a requirement, where can I find information about this, as I
  haven't been able to locate anything.

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to generate this error follows.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="document.xsd">
    <Container Name="Container">
        <Bar a="bar" />
        <Foo a="foo" />
    </Container>
</Document>
```

**Non-Working XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- Base type. -->
    <xs:complexType name="base_t">
        <xs:attribute name="a" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- Elements. -->
    <xs:element name="Foo" type="base_t" />
    <xs:element name="Bar" type="base_t" />
    <xs:element name="Baz" type="base_t" />

    <!-- Container definition. -->
    <xs:element name="Container">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:ID" use="required" />
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="Foo" />
                <xs:element ref="Bar" />
                <xs:element ref="Baz" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- Document definition. -->
    <xs:element name="Document">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Container" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Working XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- Base type. -->
    <xs:complexType name="base_t">
        <xs:attribute name="a" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- Elements. -->
    <xs:element name="Foo" type="base_t" />
    <xs:element name="Bar" type="base_t" />
    <xs:element name="Baz" type="base_t" />

    <!-- Container definition. -->
    <xs:element name="Container">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="Foo" />
                <xs:element ref="Bar" />
                <xs:element ref="Baz" />
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:ID" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- Document definition. -->
    <xs:element name="Document">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Container" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `xsd:attribute` must ***follow***, not *precede*, `xsd:choice`.  This is part of the [W3C Recommendation for XSD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) – not an idiosyncrasy of the XSD processor you're using.

See [3.4.2 XML Representation of Complex Type Definitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-type) for the part of the recommendation that covers this:

```
<complexType
  abstract = boolean : false
  block = (#all | List of (extension | restriction)) 
  final = (#all | List of (extension | restriction)) 
  id = ID
  mixed = boolean : false
  name = NCName
  {any attributes with non-schema namespace . . .}>
  Content: (annotation?, 
            (simpleContent | complexContent | 
             ((group | all | choice | sequence)?,
              ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?))))
</complexType>
```

Comment: This is counterintuitive to me, but I can live with that.  Thanks.